# jquery.data() is either not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to use the 
$().load() function to cache some information but when I test it using a text input and alert it does not seem to work. I get an undefined in the alert box. Please advise me.

```
$(function () {
    $("#searchbutton").click(function () {
        var string = $("#searchtext").val();
        $("#searchtext").data("Search", "hello");
        window.open("Tables.html");

    });
});
```

after Tables.html opens

```
$(function () {

    alert(($("#searchtext").data("Search")));


});
```

I even tried this now

```
$(function () {
    $("#searchbutton").click(function () {
        var string = $("#searchtext").val();
        sessionStorage.setItem('YO', string);
        window.open("Tables.html");

    });
});
```

and this

```
$(function () {

    var retrieve = sessionStorage.getItem('YO')
    alert(($().data(retrieve)));


});
```

still undefined.

Comment: Where are you trying to get the data from? add something to $()

Comment: https://api.jquery.com/data/